# FFMPEG on Android with libmp3lame

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, ffmpeg, lame

I' build an app for android to convert videos to audio.
Im using ffmpeg for the process. (Im using the precompiled version from [here](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java))

At the moment its only possible to convert to *.wav and not to *.mp3.

So im asking u if **anybody can provide me a compiled version supporting the libmp3lame-library?**

Or can anybody explane to me how to compile it myself.
Ive tried to, but im getting some errors all the time and i dont know how to handle them.

Ive tried to compile it myself with this setup:

- Ubuntu x64
- Android NDK-r10
- ffmpeg SourceCode from Feb-02-2014
- libmp3lame-dev

following [this tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/)

of course ive added 
**--enable-libmp3lame** to the **./configuration**

thanks anyways 

and sorry for the bad english

Comment: I've got errors too. Have you solved it? This question describes the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449169/skipping-incompatible-libmp3lame-a-while-searching-mp3lame-ffmpeg